# Finding consecutive last letters: list index out of range when trying to loop through consecutive letters

Tags: python

I am trying to find the words with the most consecutive last letters. For example in this string:

```
asd atsd ard afs agrs args ats
```

Here the output should be: `"afs agrs args ats"`.

I am trying to do this with the following loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(wordlist)):
    current_letter = wordlist[i][-1]
    next_letter == wordlist[i+1][-1]
    if current_letter = next_letter:
        longest_sequence.append(current_letter)
```

Here after, I will compare length of the longest sequence to length of the `current_sequence`, and update it if `current_sequence` is longer.

However, I am getting a `list index out of range error`. I do understand why this is, but I do not understand how I can solve this error without loosing the last letter of my list (through: `range(0,len(wordlist) - 1`).

I have now changed the code to:

```
for i in range(0,len(wordlist) - 2):
    if wordlist[i][-1] == wordlist[i+1][-1]:
        print(wordlist[i], wordlist[i+1])
```

However, when inputting `"tts attgs ghf ghhf loll lpl lpl wow"` I only get the following: `"tts attgs ghf ghhf loll lpl lpl lpl"`. So when adding the second word in the consecutive pair, I seem to create a double when there are 3 consecutive endings. However I do not understand why this happens.

Comment: Indeed, this is a typo. i have edited this now

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your condition at all. As far as I can tell, *every* word has exactly one "last letter", the one that's rightmost when you write it out. And as far as I can tell, the thing that distinguishes the words you want in your sample output from the words you don't want, is that the words you want end in "s" while the words you don't want end in "d".

Comment: Does it actually cause problems to not include the last index? When `i` is `len(wordlist) - 2`, `wordlist[i+1][-1]` is already the last element.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have changed len(wordlist) -1 to len(wordlist) - 2 and this indeed seems to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am getting a list index out of range error. I do understand why this is, but i do not understand how i can solve this error without loosing the last letter of my list (throug: range(0,len(wordlist) - 1)

Actually, you can use `range(0,len(wordlist-1))` and you won't lose the last letter.  `next_letter` will just be the last letter.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong here.  First, your range of `i` includes the index of the last word, but then you do `wordlist[i+1]`, which will be out of range on the last iteration of the range.

`next_letter == wordlist[i+1][-1]` is a comparison, not an assignment

`if current_letter = next_letter:` is an assignment, not a comparison

If this were a comparison, and if it were `False`, wouldn't you then want to take some action, like do something with what's in `longest_sequence` and then clear it before moving on?

Here's a sort of summary of all of this by way of fixing the problems with your code and pointing out where you need some additional logic:

```
for i in range(0, len(wordlist) - 1):
    current_letter = wordlist[i][-1]
    next_letter = wordlist[i + 1][-1]
    if current_letter == next_letter:
        longest_sequence.append(current_letter)
    else:
        pass # Do something here with what you've accumulated in longest_sequence
```

Comment: I understand that [i+1] would be out of range. However, its unclear to me how i would compare one word with the next word without using [i+1]?

Comment: @jvl77 It's not the `i+1` that's the problem, it's the range of values `i` can take.  You're going one iteration too far.  You want the last `i` to be `len(wordlist) - 2` so that adding 1 to that gives you the index of the last word in the list.

Comment: Thank you! Thats very clear indeed. However, I do not understand why i would use an else here. As I only want to append longest_sequence in case of two consecutive last letters, and otherwise will add nothing

Comment: But as soon as the test fails, the next word you add to `longest_sequence1` won't have the same last letter as the previous word, right? If you have `foo foo bar foo foo`, you want the longest sequence to be 2 words long, not 4, right?  Your current code will give you an answer of 4 words being consecutive

Comment: Yes you are right indeed. Thank you for the insight!